# How to store numbers into an integer array according to its index in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and I am trying to store these numbers : 78, 29, 30, 27, 30 into an integer array according to its index.

This is my current code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int numarray [5] = {78, 29, 30, 27, 30};


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        numarray[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want 78 to be stored at numarray[78] (or numarray[77])?

Comment: What do you mean by "storing into an integer array accroding to its index"? Whats the expected result? You did notice the missing `,` between `30` and `27`?

Comment: Not to mention that 30 comes twice in your array.

Answer (score 0):

`int numarray [5]` means your array has only 5 indices i.e 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

You need to have an array big enough. The biggest number in your array is 78 so you need to have an array of size 79.

For example:

```
int numarray[79];
numarray[78] = 78
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to store a number in a container with a custom (user-defined) index.

C-style array (which `numarray` is) is a *sequence container*. It contains a sequence of values, an index is used only to get the value from it.

What you are looking for is an **associative** container (a key-value map).

Take a look at `std::map`.